# Printing Booklet Page Size in Adobe Reader 4-in-1

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat, layout, paper

So I have a 70 page pdf document that I'm trying to condense to a small booklet.

I tried creating a formula to manually to perform it but it got ugly fast.

```
35,36,34,37,17,54,16,55,33,38,32,39,15,56,14,57,31,40,30,41,13,58,12,59
29,42,28,43,11,60,10,61,27,44,26,45,9,62,8,63,25,46,24,47,7,64,6,65
23,48,22,49,5,66,4,67,21,50,20,51,3,68,2,69,19,52,18,53,1,70
```

Once I print the booklet I should be able to cut the sheets in half and set the bottom half behind the top and staple it for a simple book.

Which means

Page 1 should have pages 35,36,17,54,34,37,16,55
Page 2 should have pages 33,38,15,56,32,39,14,57
And several pages later
Page 9 should have pages 19,52,1,70,18,53

But manually doing this is a headache and it seems like the booklet function should contain functionality that can perform this.

I'm using a commercial Konica Minolta C452